# How does a phone connect to the internet?

Tags: cellphone

How does a Samsung Galaxy S3 phone connect to the internet? Is it possible to surgically remove these parts involved so that one can still make calls but not connect to the internet?

Comment: Perhaps http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ is a better place?

Comment: Probably a lot easier to get someone who can write an android app to somehow inhibit internet usage.

Comment: Ok.... Do you guys know of any phones these days that ONLY offer calling functionality (and maybe texting also), but absolutely no internet access? It's for myself.

Comment: IF you're using Android, you can turn off both Wifi and Mobile Data (both 3G and 4G), and also make sure that there's no bluetooth sharing.  Then you will get calls and texts, but no internet data of any kind.

Comment: Yes, but the user can just turn them back on as easily as he turned them off.

Comment: Just get a [dumb phone](http://www.complex.com/tech/2011/02/keep-it-simple-the-10-best-dumb-phones-available-now/) already.

Comment: get a SIM card phone plan/pre-paid option that has no data allowance? I guess the phone can still connect via wifi and tethering but how likely is that to happen? who are you trying to cut off from the real world?

Answer (score 4):

A smartphone can connect to the Internet in several ways: via the cell netowrk, via a local WiFi connection, or maybe even via a USB or Bluetooth connection. The physical components used for each of these connections are also used for other things, so no, you can't physically remove them without affecting functionality you want to preserve.